# Using Regex to add spaces in string based on capitalization?

Tags: python, regex

I want to put a space between the last consecutive uppercase and between uppercase and lowercase. For example:

> **HelloWorld**  -> *Hello World*
>
> **HELloworld**  -> *HE Lloworld*
>
> **HElloWOrld** -> *H Ello W Orld*

So far I have the following code, that separates from lowercase to uppercase

`newkey = " ".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', key))`

Comment: why `HElloWOrld -> H Ello W Orld` is not `HElloWOrld -> H Ello WOrld` ?

Comment: Because every separate word have at most 1 uppercase unless it is the first word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try making two regex substitutions:

```
inp = "HElloWOrld"
out = re.sub(r'([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])', '\\1 \\2', inp)
out = re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1 \\2', out)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
H Ello W Orld
```

The first call replaces a capital letter which is followed by another capital letter and a lowercase letter.  The second call splits a lowercase/uppercase boundary.

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you might use an alternation with a positive lookahead.

*Pattern*

```
(?:[A-Z]+|[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-z]` Match a-z
- `)` Close group
- `(?=[A-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is A-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y5XetV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3f0FjG)

In the replacement use the full match followed by a space `r"\g<0> "`

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"(?:[A-Z]+|[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"
test_str = ("HelloWorld\n\n"
    "HELloworld\n\n"
    "HElloWOrld\n")

result = re.sub(regex, r"\g<0> ", test_str)
print (result)
```

*Output*

```
Hello World

HE Lloworld

H Ello W Orld
```